# Customize overview bar color in Android app developed with Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I've developed an app using Cordova/Phonegap and web technologies, and want to personalize it a little bit, but I'm having trouble finding how.

In android, when users press the Overview button (the squared one), they can see an overview with cards for each of the open apps, these cards have a top bar with an icon and the name of the app. As shown in this screenshot:

[image: grey bar for 90 seconds app]

By default the bar color is gray, but I would want it to be a different color that matches better the colors in my app. This is something that can be seen in other apps, that have different colors for that bar (e.g.: Chrome bar is blue, Email bar is orange, etc):

[image: example showing other apps with other color bars]

I tried using the [`theme-color`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android) meta value, but that didn't do anything. I also tried the [status-bar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar), this one changed the status bar when the app is open, but still shows the default gray bar in the overview card mode.

Is it possible to customize this overview bar color with Cordova/Phonegap? How would it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-headercolor
```

Usage:

-.cs

```
window.plugins.headerColor.tint("#becb29");
```

**OR**

-config.xml

```
<preference name="HeaderColor" value="#becb29" />
```

[Here is doc.](https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-headercolor)

[image]

Comment: This did the trick. One question though: it works without using the `window.plugins.headerColor.tint("#becb29");`, is that part really necessary?

Comment: You can use it in config.xml or some .cs.

Answer (score 1):

This answer pretty much sums it up:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/29291928/6709110

The method you are looking for is

```
setTaskDescription(new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(label, icon, color));
```

Here is the link to the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTaskDescription(android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription)

Comment: This may work, but it's not what I am looking for. This method requires changing the Java files, but I am using Cordova and only working with HTML/JavaScript